# Auto-Pairing in LightTable

Tags: configuration, clojure, lighttable

I have set up auto-pairing for Light Table for the characters `"({[` and their counterparts (Important Note: I using the german keyboard layout). This is was done by adding `[:app :lt.objs.settings/pair-keymap-diffs]` to my user behaviors (does the trick for `"`) and

```
[:editor "alt-[" (:editor.open-pair "[")]
[:editor "alt-{" (:editor.open-pair "{")]
[:editor "alt-]" (:editor.close-pair "]")]
[:editor "alt-}" (:editor.close-pair "}")]
```

to my user keymaps. When I now type a `{`, into the editor a `[]` is inserted. How do I set it up properly? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer could be found in [this github issue](https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable/issues/2003). I removed the above code from my keymaps and instead added the following code to my behaviors:

```
;; Normal brackets autoclose
[:app :lt.objs.editor/load-addon ["edit/closebrackets.js"]]
[:editor :lt.objs.editor/set-codemirror-flags {:autoCloseBrackets true}]
```

You might have to remove the lighttable autoclose plugin:

```
[:editor :-lt.objs.settings/pair-keymap-diffs]
```